# Selecting features based on one to many relation in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, polygon, select-by-attribute, table, one-to-many

There are two layers: [1] one is a polygon layer with an `"ID"`, [2] the other one is a table with one or many owners for each `"ID"`.

My goal is to select every polygon owned by a specific person or organisation. No matter how hard I try, I did not achieve my goal. The selecting tool doesn't work when I enter criteria from the related table.

How can I do this?

Comment: It seem the select be relationship plugin https://github.com/pyarchinit/selectbyrelationship_repo/wiki will solve your problem (you need to allow experimental plugin)

Comment: What if you apply a join firstly and then selection?

Answer (score 3):

Apart from joining or virtual layer (this would be another, slightly more complex solution), you can simply use [Select by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html?#select-by-expression) on the layer `polygon` with this expression. In the second last line, replace `Smith` with the name you're looking for:

```
array_contains( 
    with_variable(
        'id',
        id, 
        aggregate( 
            'owner', 
            'array_agg', 
            owner, 
            filter:=id=@id
        )
    ),
    'Smith'
)
```

This is based on the following layer and attribute field names. Change the names accordingly above if you use other names:

1. Polygon layer `polygon` with field `id`
2. Attribute only layer named `owner` with field `id` and `owner`

*The expression looks in the `owner` layer for all features with attribute `owner='Smith', gets the` id`for this features and then selects all polygons which have an identical`id`:*

[image]

Comment: Professor of expressions :)

Comment: Awarded by you, this title honors me. The title professor of virtual layers is still open, to my knowledge ;-)

Comment: I am just a student :)

Comment: So am I - that's basically what this site here is about...